# Android AsyncTask, HTTP Request and Parsing

Tags: java, parsing, android, asynchronous, web-services

I am working on Android applications for last 2 years and about 80% applications I have developed involve web-services consumption followed by some sort of XML or JSON parsing. Initially, when I had to call a web service, I had to create a separate `AsyncTask` class and then parsing was also the part of that AsyncTask class. The HTTP request sending and other stuff was being handled in my `ConnectionManager` class. Then I realized there should be some general and single structure which can handle such things like `Async` call, `HttpGet` and `HttpPost` and parsing stuff. So I created this simple structure.

Now my question is, what changes and improvements I can add to make it work better and handle such different use cases?

**TaskResult.class**

```
public class TaskResult {

    public static int CODE_ERROR = 0;
    public static int CODE_SUCCESS = 1;

    public int code = CODE_ERROR;
    public String message = null;
    private Object data = null;

    public Object getResultData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setResultData(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

**BaseParser.class**

```
public interface BaseParser {
    public TaskResult parse(InputStream in);
}
```

**ConnectionManager.class**

```
public class ConnectionManager {

    private  ArrayList <NameValuePair> params;
    private  ArrayList <NameValuePair> headers;
    private String url;

    public static int GET_REQUEST = 0;
    public static int POST_REQUEST = 1;

    private int mRequestType = POST_REQUEST;

    public ConnectionManager() {
        params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        headers = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    }

    public void addParam(String name, String value) {
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
    }

    public void addHeader(String name, String value) {
        headers.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
    }

    public void setRequestType(int type) {
        mRequestType = type;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public InputStream getHttpInputStream() throws ClientProtocolException, Exception {
        if(url == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
        if(mRequestType == POST_REQUEST) {
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
            request.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, Boolean.FALSE);
            for(int i = 0; i < headers.size(); i++) {
                StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(headers.get(i).getValue(), "UTF-8");
                request.setEntity(entity);
            }

            if(!params.isEmpty()){
                HttpEntity httpEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8);
                request.setEntity(httpEntity);
            }

            DefaultHttpClient mClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse httpResponse;
            httpResponse = mClient.execute(request);
            HttpEntity mEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            if (mEntity != null) {
                return mEntity.getContent();
            }
        }
        else if(mRequestType == GET_REQUEST) {
            String queryString = ""; 
            for(int i = 0; i < params.size(); i++) {
                if(i == 0) {
                    queryString = queryString + params.get(i).getName( ) + "=" + params.get(i).getValue();
                }
                else {
                    queryString = queryString + "&" + params.get(i).getName( ) + "=" + params.get(i).getValue();
                }
            }
            DefaultHttpClient mClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url + queryString);

            HttpResponse httpResponse;
            httpResponse = mClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity mEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            if (mEntity != null) {
                return mEntity.getContent();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

**BaseAsyncTask.class**

```
public class BaseAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, TaskResult>{

    ConnectionManager mConnectionManager = null;
    OnTaskCompleteListener mListener;
    BaseParser mParser;

    public BaseAsyncTask.class() {
        mConnectionManager = new ConnectionManager();
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected TaskResult doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String message = "";
        try {
            InputStream in = mConnectionManager.getTestInputStream();
            return mParser.parse(in);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            message = e.getMessage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            message = e.getMessage();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            message = e.getMessage();
        }

        TaskResult rs = new TaskResult();
        rs.message = "Internal error. Please try later." + message;
        return rs;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(TaskResult result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        mListener.onComplete(result);
    }

    public void setRequestType(int type) {
        mConnectionManager.setRequestType(type);
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        mConnectionManager.setUrl(url);
    }

    public void addParam(String name, String value) {
        mConnectionManager.addParam(name, value);
    }

    public void addHeader(String name, String value) {
        mConnectionManager.addHeader(name, value);
    }

    public void setCallbackListener(OnTaskCompleteListener listener) {
        this.mListener = listener;
    }

    public void setParser(BaseParser parser) {
        this.mParser = parser;
    }

    public interface OnTaskCompleteListener {
        public void onComplete(TaskResult rs);
    }

}
```

and this is how I call a web-service:

```
        BaseAsyncTask mAsyncTask = new BaseAsyncTask();
        mAsyncTask.setUrl(WEB_URL);
        mAsyncTask.addParam("id", "some_id");
        mAsyncTask.setRequestType(ConnectionManager.GET_REQUEST);
        mAsyncTask.setCallbackListener(callbackListener);
        mAsyncTask.setParser(new MyListingParser());
        mAsyncTask.execute();

    public class MyListingParser implements BaseParser {

    @Override
    public TaskResult parse(InputStream in) {
        TaskResult result = new TaskResult();
        // convert inputstream to string and then parse
        ArrayList<MyClass> data = parseString(in);
        result.setResultData(data);
        result.code = TaskResult.CODE_SUCCESS;
        return result;
    }

}

    private OnTaskCompleteListener callbackListener = new OnTaskCompleteListener() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(TaskResult rs) {

            if(rs.code == TaskResult.CODE_ERROR) {
                // handle error
            }
            else if(rs.code == TaskResult.CODE_SUCCESS) {
                // handle success case like getting data from TaskResult and populating some listview or other stuff
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 3):

Your idea seems quite feasible, I just had a brief look through and these would be my suggestions:

1. TaskResult class

   - "code" and "message" members should probably be encapsulated via getter/setter with proper namings.
2. ConnectionManager class

   - Depending on your scenario maybe you should consider calling "shutdown" on your mClient member.
   - When creating your queryString you should use String.format() instead of manually concatenating strings.
   - The getHttpInputStream() method could suffer a bit of refactoring, you have common code and behaviour in both if/else branches.

Other then that, imo the code looks okey.

Comment: Yeah, your points are very noteworthy and I will add them to my original code.

Answer (score 3):

I use [volley library](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhv8l9F44qo) to do these work.
Volley is a library developed by Google, it is tried and tested.
It has other features network response caching, network image caching, request cancelation etc..

Answer (score 1):

It's simple and elegant and useful for many cases but I'd do something else

1. I would enhance `HttpRequest` with `Multipart` (I know, it's not what you wanted but it's very useful for Http Connections, if you want to upload/download something,Multipart is a MUST)
2. I would enhance `HttpResponse` instead `TaskResult` and there, I would also use Multipart

Answer (score 1):

Just one thing I'd like to mention here.

1. In your AsyncTask you are not doing anything in `onPreExecute()` so I would remove it.